# C pthreads: police officer that allows cars to pass through a one way bridge

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm implementing a problem in C using pthreads, it is about an old bridge which crosses a river from east to west. Since it is a small bridge, cars can only go
in one direction.
I have solved the problem of creating the threads which will cross the bridge (use the critical region) and they cross if there are no cars on the bridge or if the cars crossing are going the same direction.
Next step is to make another thread that has to run during the entire process, this thread has to allow the pass in one direction to a certain amount of cars and then to the other direction, like a police officer would do. Right now I'm doing the following:
I'm creating a thread (police officer):

```
 pthread_create(&policeOfficer, NULL, officerFunction, &bridge);
```

Before the creation of the "car" threads:

```
pthread_t thread[totalCars];
int randomDir;
int contWest = 0;
int contEast = 0;
while (contWest + contEast < totalCars) {

    randomDir = (int) (rand() % 2); //random number to define the direction (east/west)

    if (contWest < westCars && randomDir == 1) {

        contWest++;
        //sleep(1);

        pthread_create(&thread[(contWest + contEast) - 1], NULL, west, &bridge);
    } else if (contEast < eastCars && randomDir == 0) {

        contEste++;
        //sleep(1); 

        pthread_create(&thread[(contwest + contEast) - 1], NULL, east, &bridge);
    }
}
```

The function that the "officer" executes is the following (this is not working):

```
static void* officer(void *data) {

bridge *pBridge = (bridge *) data;
while(totalThreads>=0){
    while(pBridge->numberOfCars <= carsAllowed);//busy waiting I think. numberOfCars is the actual number of cars at the bridge (crossing)
        if(pBridge->direction == WEST){
        pBridge->direction = EAST;
        }else{
        pBridge->direction = WEST; 
}
     }
return NULL;
}
```

I'm getting used to work with threads and arrays of threads but not with a thread to control another threads so I don't know if this is right. The functions that controls how the threads use the bridge are all working so I don't think I need to modify them that much.
I think the "officer" just have to allow a certain amount of cars to cross in one direction or the other (changing the bridge direction after cars pass through) so I hope you can help me on this one.
Thanks!

Comment: Hint: you definitely need some indication for which way traffic is allowed to travel, but you also need to stop traffic in both directions while you are switching directions, to allow the cars going one direction to clear, before admitting cars to go the other direction -- you might think 3 or 4 states (Forward, ForwardClear, Reverse, ReverseClear)...

Comment: You need to use APIs that implement memory barriers if you want writes in one thread to be seen by reads in another.  See [this article](http://www.domaigne.com/blog/computing/mutex-and-memory-visibility/) for more info.

Comment: gonna read that thing